# google app engine session

Tags: java, google-app-engine

1. what is java app engine,default session time out ?
2. will that be any bad impact if we set sesion time out to very very long time, since google app engine session is just store in datastore by default? (just like facebook, each time you go to the page, the session still exist forever) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Default session timeout is set to 30 Minutes. (you can verify it calling [getMaxInactiveInterval](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29) method)
2. With that fairly limited info about your app, I don't see any impact.
   Using `setMaxInactiveInterval(-1)` indicates that the Session should never timeout.
   Keep in mind that you also need to overwrite the JSESSIONID cookie MaxAge to prevent to lose the Session when the browser is closed.

Comment: will that case in increase usage of memory/resources in appengine?

Comment: yes, because you will end with many useless active sessions on the _ah_SESSION table.

Comment: It seems that GAE is not obeying req.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(x) anymore. It sets the session expires value in memcache / datastore to 1 day from now, by default. However I found a way to change this, by adding the following to web.xml. <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20160</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

Answer (score 1):

1. I've just tested on my GAE webapp and the default timeout is getMaxInactiveInterval()=86400 (s) = 24 hours = 1 day