# What is the session limit of Google app engine freemium

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a simple php website hosted in Google App Engine. I am confused about it's session quaota which is 27. I have few pages like 'about us', 'services', 'products' and 'contact' form. Which are very generic pages. As I know, Google App Engine's “freemium” business model offering basic features for free. 5 million pageviews a month etc.

But in the “freemium” it has a session limit and I do not know what will happen to the website if it will read the session limit.

Thanks!

Comment: where did you see the session quota mentioned?

Comment: Please do let me know about 28 free instance-hours per day can it able to handel . 5 million pageviews a month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks like you actually meant the instance-hours quota. When the app hits that quota (or any other quota for that matter) it stops working until the quota is replenished. As described in [When a resource is depleted](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted) and [How resources are replenished](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#How_Resources_are_Replenished).

As for being able to translate 5 million requests/month into instance-hours - extremely difficult, if even possible. It totally depends on:

- how your app is implemented - how long does it take an instance to handle a request
- your app's scaling configuration - only the automatic scaling has 28 free instance-hours: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Instances
- your app's instance class configuration - different classes handle requests at different speeds and count differently in instance hours
- what's the incoming request pattern/distribution - if you have peaks of requests hitting the app GAE will spawn additional (dynamic) instances to handle the load, possibly depleting the daily free quota. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/scaling).

The only real way to get and estimate is to build, run and measure your app's usage (within the free quota) and from there extrapolate.

IMHO it's more cost effective to actually go for billed apps and control costs through the daily spending limit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "session" limit on Google AppEgnine. You are limited by resource usage rather then usage patterns.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas for reference.

Comment: Please do let me know about 28 free instance-hours per day can it able to handel . 5 million pageviews a month ?

Comment: If you use Go (for example) you can serve a dynamic "page" in about 50ms on if you have right design but it has no upper limit (depends on requirements & implementation). Or you can use static pages for some of your content that I believe does not count towards instance hours. So do the math and calculate how much can you serve on a free quota. But you also need take into account traffic limits (Bandwidth).  You have 1GB per day = 30GB per month. That's gives you about 6KB per "page" within free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Google app engine uses the datastore and memcached to store session data, so keep an eye on the usage these resources in your console to check your not approaching your free quota. I believe this is the only limiting factor.

I think session data lasts a day ([google app engine session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496144/google-app-engine-session))